# Firebase Database "equalTo" without ordering

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Let's say I have this object in db

```
{
   value:60
   status:PLAYING  // could be PLAYING or FINISHED for simplicity
}
```

and I want to listen this object, or want to be notified when `status` becomes `FINISHED`

Currently following is not working

```
myRef.child("status").equalTo("PLAYING").addValueEventLisener...
```

it just triggers `onDataChange` regardless of `status` and returns snapshot value as `null`

On the other hand, if I omit `PLAYING` and use as following:

```
    myRef.child("status").addValueEventLisener...
```

`onDataChange` is triggered as usual and **snapshot value is not** `null`

I have tried `orderByChild` it is not helping or I am doing things wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That is an `orderByValue()` query:

```
myRef.child("status").orderByValue().equalTo("PLAYING")
```

Comment: You're calling `orderByChild`, my code is using `orderByValue()`. If that doesn't help for you, update your question to include more context. As it stands there is not enough JSON to see what the ordering would do and we can't know what `myRef` point to.